# exam the ADF test with different lags in R

Tags: r

I want to test the data generated by a model y= ρy −1 + ut, where ρ<=1, and ut= et-θet-1, and θ is the value of parameter of moving average process. I've run the following code in R but, still don't obtain the same result as shown in Schwert 1989 simulation unit root test. The code:

```
    library{tseries}
    n<-100 #### number of obervations
    i <-0  ##### number of simulation
    j <-0 ##### account the number of accept the hypothesis 
    for (i in 1:5000)
    {
    fun<-rnorm(n)  
    sim<-arima.sim(model=list(ma=0,order=c(0,0,1)),n=n,innov=fun)
    x<-arima.sim(model=list(ar=0.95,order=c(1,0,0)),n=n,innov=sim)
    m<-adf.test(x,k=1)

    if (m$p.value<0.05){
       j<-(j+1)}
    }
    j/5000
```